# Outputting a conditional echo to another page

Tags: php, codeigniter, echo

I'm using Code Ignitor for this project. Within my `login Controller` I have a function that outputs an echo statement based on a conditional statement.

This function is called on a page, and when its executed, it redirects to my `forgot_password_result.php`. I would like the echo statement to appear on the `forgot_password_result.php` file.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` variables to pass the data to `forgot_password_result.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->load->library ( 'session' );
 $this->session->set_userdata ( 'forgot_password_message', $message );
```

And in the view file.

```
 $message = $this->session->userdata ( 'forgot_password_message' );
 $this->session->set_userdata ( 'forgot_password_message', NULL );
```

So we display the message only one time

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").

Note: Flash variables are prefaced with "flash_" so avoid this prefix in your own session names.

To add flashdata:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

You can also pass an array to `set_flashdata()`, in the same manner as `set_userdata()`.

To read a flashdata variable:

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

If you find that you need to preserve a flashdata variable through an additional request, you can do so using the `keep_flashdata()` function.

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
```

Note:- Flashdata will work only if the next page(where the message is to be displayed) is loaded using `redirect()` function.